# reading files from one folders through multiple instances

Tags: java, apache-camel, spring-integration

I have a folder where an upstream system dumps the files which are input for my application. My application read those files, process them and then output in some directory. Since the number of input file is large, I decided to run multiple instances of my application and all the instances will read the same input directory for input files. Now, since multiple instances will read the same folder,  how can I prevent multiple instance from reading the same file at same time?

PS: I thought of using Spring Integration with NIO lock, but once you lock the file even the same thread will not be able to read the file.
Camel handles the lock but it locks the whole directory and also doesn't handle the scenarios for that fraction of time where 2 instances are trying to get the file which is not yet locked.

Any suggestion will be helpful.

Comment: Your first route could poll for files, copy them to a 'queued' directory and create a message on a queue, specifying the file name. Then another route could consume the queued message. If you have one instance of the first and multiple instances of the second, will the former still become a bottleneck?

Answer (score 3):

Spring Integration provides `FileSystemPersistentAcceptOnceFileListFilter` for this purpose. You can configure it with shared `ConcurrentMetadataStore` impl, e.g. `RedisMetadataStore` or `ZookeeperMetadataStore`.

And only one application instance will accept one file.

Although there is some limitation that all the files may be applied only by the one instance:

```
private void scanInputDirectory() {
    List<File> filteredFiles = this.scanner.listFiles(this.directory);
    Set<File> freshFiles = new LinkedHashSet<File>(filteredFiles);
    if (!freshFiles.isEmpty()) {
        this.toBeReceived.addAll(freshFiles);
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Added to queue: " + freshFiles);
        }
    }
}
```

You can overcome the singleton problem with distributed `MessageChannel`, e.g. `SubscribableJmsChannel`, `PublishSubscribeAmqpChannel` or any other `MessageStore`-based queue channel solution.

Comment: What i could understand is that using this we are assigning\tying listof files to one specific instance, but we don't have control which all files would be assigned to one instance and that could ruin the purpose of doing parallel processing of files

Comment: One more time. You configure `channel` for `<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>` as a distributed one. And even one instance will pick up all the files via that filter, you always can distribute them via downstream flow.

Answer (score 1):

I would not do this way because reading a folder with multiple instances is just going to complicate your flow.

I would instead have a single route which reads the files and puts the content on a queue (it can be jms, amqp whatever) along with the filename as a header. Then you can have parallel processing on that queue and do parallel write to the destination folder. That will make your solution easier to handle and extend in case you need to read additional folders.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shadow file for each file that your application instance has read

To avoid the probleme of concurent access to the same file you need to centralize the process of checking the readability of a file in one Thread or one process, this thread / process will be synchronized and will communicate with all other application instances,

For example :

- Instance1 need to check file1 if it had been read before => it will check if this file has a shadow file also if true will communicate with the centralized thread/process to see if any other instance is already processing this file
- The centralized thread will allow the instance to process the file1 and store it reference in a pool list which will be used to prevent any other instance to process this file
- Instance1  has finished processing the file also it will create the shadow file once done it will communicate with the centralized thread to remove the reference of this file from the pool list

Every instance need to perform two check levels before accessing to a file :

- Check if the file has a shadow file with the same name (which means it has been read before)
- If the first condition is true, check if the file is currently in process by any other instance by using the centralized process.

Comment: but what if 2 instances try to access the same file ... which instance will get the access to create the shadow file.. how can we control this confrontation of threads